# Where are the Friendselector changes?

Tags: facebook, multi-friend-selector

We are making a Facebook app and want to integrate Facebook Friendselector.

The guys who are making the app tell me that starting 1/4/2012 we can only invite 1 friend at a time. Is this true? And what can we do about it? We want to select multiple friends.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where those "guys" get their info, but there's nothing about this in the [Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), or in the documentation of the [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) itself.

Maybe they were referring to the [Send Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which indeed can only be used for one friend (though the user can then add more on his own), but even if they were talking about this dialog, then you don't have to use this one, you can stay with the Requests Dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, We want to select multiple friends and sent them a private message not a storie, we just want to add a little text. Does that change anything?

Comment: The friends selector thing is not for sending private messages but to invite users to interact with the app. If you want to send a private message then you'll need to use the *Send Dialog* which I linked in my answer. As for adding a message, you can't do that, facebook used to let apps add a message for the user but removed that completely cuz apps misused it.  Now only the users themselves can write the message.